# Unable to launch event onCreateConfirm and onEditConfirm

Tags: angular, typescript

I work with the free Template ngx-admin,

in this component "EtatAvancementComponent"

i want to lunch this 2 events "onCreateConfirm" and "onEditConfirm" in the classe "etat-avancement.component.ts when i click in there button:

this is my "etat-avancement.component.html"

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    Liste Des Etats Avancements
  </nb-card-header>

  <nb-card-body>
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" 
(editConfirm)="onEditConfirm($event)"      
(createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)"     
(deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" >
    </ng2-smart-table>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

---

and this is my "etat-avancement.component.ts" :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { SmartTableData } from '../../../@core/data/smart-table';
import {RestService} from '../../../rest.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-smart-table',
  templateUrl: './etat-avancement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./etat-avancement.component.scss'], 
})
export class EtatAvancementComponent {

  settings = {
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      confirmAdd: true,
      createConfirm: true,
    },
    edit: {
     editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
     saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
     cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
     confirmAdd: true,
     createConfirm: true,
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
      link: {
        title: 'ID',
        type: 'string',
      },
      nom_etat_avancement: {
        title: 'Nom D\'Etat D\'Avancement',
        type: 'string',
      },
      descri_avanacement: {
         title: 'Description Etat D\'Avancement',
        type: 'string',
      },
    },
  };

  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
  etat: any = [] ;

  constructor(private service: SmartTableData ,  public rest: RestService) {
      this.rest.getEtatAvancements().subscribe((data: any) => {
        data.content.forEach((key: any , val: any) => {
        this.etat.push({'link' : data['content'] 
   [val].links[val].href.slice(-1) ,
           'nom_etat_avancement' : data['content'][val].nomEtatAvancement ,
          'descri_avanacement' : data['content'][val].descriAvanacement});
      });
        // console.log(this.etat);
        this.source.load(this.etat);
    });


  }

  // Event De Window.confirm


  onDeleteConfirm(event): void {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Etat Avancement Number :' + event.data.link + ' ?')) {
      //
      console.log(event.data.link);
     this.rest.deleteEtatAvancement(event.data.link);
      //
       event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

   onCreateConfirm(event): void {
    console.log('On Create Confirm !!!!');
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to Create This Line')) {
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

  onEditConfirm(event): void {
     console.log('On Edit Confirm !!!!');
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit This Line')) {
       event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

  }
```

The event onDeleteConfirm(event) work correctly, but the problem is with the other 2 events.

Comment: Hi @Moamed, Is issue still there?

Comment: Yes, i'm blocked at this situation

Comment: @Moamed can you please update your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in your settings.

```
add: {
   confirmCreate: true
},
columns:{
   ...
}
,
actions: {
  position: 'right',
  add: true,
  edit: true
}
```

Please set your setting like [this.](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/projects/demo/src/app/pages/examples/server/advanced-example-server.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `confirmSave = true` and `confirmCreate = true` 
to you code.

check this: https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation